# Search a Block By TxId or hash

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Is there any Use-case or a flow Where a Block is searched by hash or Transaction Id in Blockchain with respect to any platform ?

Answer (score 5):

The LSCC exposes certain functions to user so that blocks and transactions stored on block storage can be queried. It provides the following five functions: (i) GetChainInfo, (ii) GetBlockByNumber,  (iii) GetBlockByHash, (iv) GetTransactionByID, and (v) GetBlockByTxID

The GetBlockByNumber functionality is used to get a serialized block. The following command retrieves a block number 3 from channel ch1.

```
$ peer chaincode query -C "" -n qscc -c '{"Args":["GetBlockByNumber", "ch1", "3"]}'
```

To get a Block by txId would be something like.

```
$ peer chaincode query -C "" -n qscc -c '{"Args":["GetBlockByTxID", "ch1", "txId"]}'
```

You can run this commands using the Fabric ClI.

More info [here](https://blockchain-fabric.blogspot.com/2018/03/system-chaincodes-in-hyperledger-fabric.html)

Comment: Link is dead...

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the most obvious use cases is to see whenever transaction with given ID has been eventually committed and in what block number. It has great potential in case of audit if you've like to dig into history updates for given key which appears in transaction starting from the block transaction was committed in.

Speaking of Hyperledger Farbic, before block is committed and each transaction in the block updates current state, there are [MVCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control) check which validates if there are two concurrent transactions in the same block which tries to update the same key. Therefore you might be willing to get the block for given transaction ID to understand why your transaction was invalidated, e.g. find other transaction which tried concurrently update same key with you.

I'd say most prominent use case IMO is to provide provenance and auditability.

Comment: In Hyperledger Provenance and auditability can be achieved by getHistoryforKey() function right so why do we need block to be queried?

Comment: Well, getHistoryforKey() exposed for chaincode only, e.g. in chaincode itself you cannot get block by transaction ID, moreover you cannot get access to the block by means of other APIs. The GetBlockByTxID and GetBlockByNumber exposed via QSCC so external observer would be to retrieve the block.

Comment: You should not be able to invoke system chaincodes from user chaincode. While you still should be able to invoke QSCC via SDK lib.

Comment: Can you answer this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46440382/usage-of-query-system-chaincode